# Paypal error 10002 (API access is disabled for this account) with correct credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

I am experiencing a 10002 paypal error (API access is disabled for this account) in the context of a Ruby on Rails application (Gemfile below) using ActiveMerchant and ActivePaypalAdaptivePayment to process paypal transactions. This is a new error which has appeared in the past few days. I am certain that the API credentials are correct.

The paypal sandbox business account was working normally earlier this week. The error occurs during a call to the paypal express gateway.

```
  def paypal_experss_payment(total_amount)
    amount = price_in_cents(total_amount)
    PAYPAL_EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(amount,
      :items => [{
        :name => (t :'label_tag.audition_apply_paymant'),
        :description => (t :'label_tag.one_time_audition'),
        :amount => amount
      }],
      :ip => request.remote_ip,
      :return_url => url_for(:action => 'apply_audition', :amount => total_amount, :params => params),
      :cancel_return_url => request.referer
    )
  end
```

I have tried creating new API credentials for the test business account, but this does not resolve the 10002 error (API access is disabled for this account).

I have tried creating a new test business account with new API credentials, but this did not resolve the error.

Also, I have tried upgrading the test business account from business verified to pro (as described in other StackOverflow questions related to this type of error), but this also has not resolved the error.

```
Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.14'

# Bundle edge Rails insteadhttps://addons.heroku.com/https://addons.heroku.com/:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'i18n', '0.6.9'

gem 'i18n-active_record', :git => 'git://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record.git', :require => 'i18n/active_record'

#Postgres Hstore feature
gem 'activerecord-postgres-hstore', "~> 0.4.1"

gem "acts_as_tree", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "best_in_place", "~> 1.1.2"
gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.3.1"

gem "dropbox-sdk"

# Amazon-s3
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk' , '1.9.5'
gem 'rake' ,'10.0.3'
#logging activity
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# front-end framework and glyphicons
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.3.3.0'
gem 'railties', '~> 3.2.14'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.13'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '4.2.0'
gem 'backstretch-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails' , '= 2.1.4'
gem 'jquery_datepicker' , '0.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails' ,'3.0.1'
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'

#User Registration
gem "devise", "~> 2.2.4"
gem "nested_form", '~> 0.3.2'

gem "simple_form", "~> 2.0.4"

gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

gem "cancan", "~> 1.6.9"

gem "rolify", "~> 3.2.0"

gem "friendly_id", :require => "friendly_id"

# To use of Pagination
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

#To integrate payment gateway
gem 'activemerchant'
gem "active_paypal_adaptive_payment"

gem 'goog_currency'
gem 'iso_country_codes'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# For PDF downlads
gem 'prawn', '~> 0.12.0'

gem 'thin', :group => :production

gem 'newrelic_rpm'
#For pre-compile assets
#gem "libv8"
#gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'

gem 'pry', :group => :development
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
#  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
#  gem 'debugger', :require => 'debugger'
  gem 'rspec-html-matchers'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem "shoulda"
  gem 'hirb'
end
#group :development do
  #gem "better_errors"
  #gem "binding_of_caller"
#end
gem 'exception_notification', '= 4.0.0'
```